# Pubkey authentication with SSH server running on Cygwin - session closes immediately

Tags: ssh, cygwin, public-key

I am connecting from Linux via SSH to a Windows machine running SSH in Cygwin. I authenticate with a certificate. The session opens but closes immediately thereafter. With password authentication it works well - the session remains active until I log out.

I have neither knowledge nor control over the server setup but their admin is unable to troubleshoot it as he has limited knowledge of both Linux and SSH himself.

So I am trying to determine what may be the causes of this behavior so that I can pass this information to the admin who can then fix their setup.

When I run ssh with the verbose output turned on, I get this:

```
debug1: Trying private key: /home/user/.ssh/identity
debug1: Offering public key: /home/user/.ssh/id_rsa
debug2: we sent a publickey packet, wait for reply
debug1: Server accepts key: pkalg ssh-rsa blen 277
debug2: input_userauth_pk_ok: fp [some MAC-like sequence]
debug1: PEM_read_PrivateKey failed
debug1: read PEM private key done: type <unknown>
Enter passphrase for key '/home/user/.ssh/id_rsa': 
debug1: read PEM private key done: type RSA
debug1: Authentication succeeded (publickey).
debug1: channel 0: new [client-session]
debug2: channel 0: send open
debug1: Entering interactive session.
debug2: callback start
debug2: client_session2_setup: id 0
debug2: channel 0: request pty-req confirm 1
debug1: Sending environment.
debug1: Sending env LANG = en_US.UTF-8
debug2: channel 0: request env confirm 0
debug2: channel 0: request shell confirm 1
debug2: fd 3 setting TCP_NODELAY
debug2: callback done
debug2: channel 0: open confirm rwindow 0 rmax 32768
debug2: channel_input_status_confirm: type 99 id 0
debug2: PTY allocation request accepted on channel 0
debug2: channel 0: rcvd adjust 131072
debug2: channel_input_status_confirm: type 99 id 0
debug2: shell request accepted on channel 0
Last login: Mon Oct 18 20:19:58 2010 from ip-xyz
debug2: channel 0: rcvd eof
debug2: channel 0: output open -> drain
debug2: channel 0: obuf empty
debug2: channel 0: close_write
debug2: channel 0: output drain -> closed
debug1: client_input_channel_req: channel 0 rtype exit-status reply 0
debug2: channel 0: rcvd close
debug2: channel 0: close_read
debug2: channel 0: input open -> closed
debug2: channel 0: almost dead
debug2: channel 0: gc: notify user
debug2: channel 0: gc: user detached
debug2: channel 0: send close
debug2: channel 0: is dead
debug2: channel 0: garbage collecting
debug1: channel 0: free: client-session, nchannels 1
Connection to example.com closed.
Transferred: sent 2544, received 3160 bytes, in 0.2 seconds
Bytes per second: sent 10327.0, received 12827.5
debug1: Exit status 255
```

(I edited some identifying but probably meaningless bits)

So it seems that right after logging in the client receives some bits it does not like and closes the connection.

(this is a cross-post from SU https://superuser.com/questions/200756/, where it arguably does not belong)

Answer (score 0):

Guessing here:

Are there any "forced-commands" in your ~/.ssh/authorized_keys on the server or for that matter any other restrictions?
If the lines there just start with "ssh-rsa AAAAB3Nz" then everything in that direction should be ok.

Comment: Nope, authorized_keys only contains my key, but I do not know about "forced commands" and if they are present in other config files

Comment: the only other place I know of where forced commands could be placed is /etc/ssh/sshd_config but as far as I know there they are always user specific and can not change based on authentication.